# How to import docs.* in akka project?

Tags: java, akka

I want import docs.actor.japi.FaultHandlingDocSample.WorkerApi.*; But I can't find the docs package which can use in maven central repository. And I don't find the information about docs package in the Akka official website.The akka version I used is 2.4.6.

Comment: That's not a published package and isn't meant for general use.

Comment: I want to run the demo in Akka documentation, What should I do to make use of this package @Ryan

Answer (score 0):

If you are still seeing this error, remove the declarations for docs.* from the top of the example code. All of the values are present in the file itself. Re-import the declarations referencing the file and the errors should resolve.